# What does operator() (... mean in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, comparator

The comparator code in C++ below is as follows:

```
struct WordGreaterComparator
{
    bool operator()(const std::string & left, const std::string & right) const
    {
        return (left > right);
    }
};
```

My question is can someone explain what exactly is going on with the part:

```
operator()(...
```

What exactly is the purpose of it and what does it mean?

Comment: It means the object is invocable.  Sometimes called "functor" or "function objects".  In modern C++, lambdas have replaced the need for them in many cases.  (Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for a functor.)

Comment: @Eljay thanks!  very helpful.